# Adding a TextBlock before another element in a ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm currently learning how to develop and building an app for windows phone 7.

If a certain value is true, I need to add a TextBlock to the ListBox before a TextBlock (say its name is `x:Name="dayTxtBx"`).

I am currently using

```
dayListBox.Items.Add(dayTxtBx);
```

to add the text box.

Any help very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean "before"? _Above_ or _to the left of_? Also, I recommend to better use Data Binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(VS.95).aspx

Comment: above. Is there a way to use data binding and insert a text box when the value of an element changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do if you're using a DataTemplate and a ValueConverter and passing the whole object into the ListBox (rather than just a string).  Assuming you have some object that looks like:

```
public class SomeObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool mTestValue;
    public bool TestValue 
    {
        get {return mTestValue;}
        set {mTestValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TestValue");}
    }
    private string mSomeText;
    public string SomeText
    {
        get {return mSomeText;}
        set {mSomeText = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeText");}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if ((name != null) && (PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

You can make a converter that looks like:

```
public class BooleanVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && (bool)value)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And add the converter to your XAML like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:BooleanVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter" />
    <UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you could have the ListBox defined in XAML like so:

```
<Listbox>
  <Listbox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orentation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Text="Only Show If Value is True" Visibility={Binding TestValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}} />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
</Listbox>
```

Might seem like a lot, but it's really pretty simple once you get started.  A great way to learn more about data binding and converters is at Jesse Liberty's blog (  http://jesseliberty.com/?s=Windows+Phone+From+Scratch ).

Comment: thanks using your visibility idea i managed to use my current implimentation with data binding.